# What was 'impure' about the last surviving red dalek?

Tags: doctor-who, dalek

In ['Revolution of the Daleks'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolution_of_the_Daleks), a special episode falling just after series 12 new Doctor Who, a creature cloned from

> the remains of the scout Dalek from episode 'Resolution'

takes over a company's manufacturing facilities, and proceeds to create loads of Daleks. The 'DNA' of these created Daleks is corrupted, perhaps because

> they were fed on liquidised humans and that's the loosey-goosey way that DNA works in new Who

and so when

> Death Squad Daleks, with the typical Dalek obsession with 'purity'

arrive, they proceed to eliminate all these created Daleks. However, the last survivor is the original creature itself, which identifies itself to the attackers, but is still categorised by them as 'impure', and is killed.

Why is this last survivor identified as impure, when after all it's

> cloned from a pure Dalek

?

Comment: The daleks being space Nazis, obsessed with racial purity, is one of the few constants that goes back to the very earliest days of *Doctor Who*.

Comment: That could be handwoven any number of ways, least of which is that even if it might be pure (by whatever definition that has these days) it spread impure daleks

Comment: Impure in thought and deed.

Comment: I beliee that Daleks believe in ideological purity as well as racial purity.. Kinda a combination of nazi/comunist.

Comment: @Buzz no it doesn't. It was ~20 years before the Daleks started caring about the purity of other Daleks.

Comment: @Questor, as if pure nazis had no care about ideology and it's purity, and were liberal about nazism.

Comment: Could it be from also feeding itself on liquefied humans?

Comment: One interpretation of the episode I've seen (and with which I agree) is that it was a dig at the "hardcore" fans and their insistence about what's in continuity and what's not.  The old school Daleks were arguing over whether or not the new Daleks "counted".

Answer (score 0):

This is a 'holding' answer which I hope can be beaten by a better one! The *only* thing I can think of is that *maybe* when the hapless scientist collected the scraps of organic matter from the casing (which everyone else believed to be empty), that organic matter was "damaged" or "corrupted" in some way, so even when it was cloned, it wasn't 'correct'? Again, in the loosey-goosey way that DNA works in new Who...